# Replace lines containing specific value but not containing some characters

Tags: bash, sed

I use the following command to replace lines containing `Mic1 Volume`:

```
sed -i 's#.*Mic1 Volume.*#<mixer name="Mic1 Volume" value0="68" />#' ysound.xml
```

Now I would like also to replace these but skip lines containing `value1` string.

How to do this using `sed` command?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
sed -i '/value1/!s#.*Mic1 Volume.*#<mixer name="Mic1 Volume" value0="68" />#' ysound.xml
        ^^^^^^^^^
```

The negation operator is `!` and is placed after the `/regex/`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same with **awk**:

```
awk '!/value1/{gsub(/Mic1 Volume./,"<mixer name="Mic1 Volume" value0="68" />")}1' File
```

To have it inplace:

```
awk '!/value1/{gsub(/Mic1 Volume./,"<mixer name="Mic1 Volume" value0="68" />")}1' File > tmp && mv tmp File
```

**Sample:**

```
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$ cat File
value0
value1
Mic1 Volume. value2
Mic1 Volume. value1
Mic1 Volume. value4
value5
value6
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$ awk '!/value1/{gsub(/Mic1 Volume./,"<mixer name="Mic1 Volume" value0="68" />")}1' File
value0
value1
<mixer name= value0=68 /> value2
Mic1 Volume. value1
<mixer name= value0=68 /> value4
value5
value6
```